# How to get tracking number and its title(FEDEX) for each item in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, fedex, shipment-tracking, dhl

I need to get a tracking number which resides in `sales_shipment_track` for each item in an order.
Right now I am iterating all items of an order.

```
foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $item) {
  echo $item->getTrackNumber();
}
```

This didnt work.
How to get a `tracking number` and its `title` i.e, FEDEX
so that I can know which carrier is that tracking number.

Answer (score 0):

```
         $tracksCollection = $order->getTracksCollection();

        foreach ($tracksCollection->getItems() as $item) {

          echo $track->getTrackNumber(); // Tracking number

             }
```

Comment: How can i do it using query with order id and get tracking number for all items under hat element, as i am iterating for items with <?php foreach ($orderInfo->getAllVisibleItems() as $item): ?> this.